# Create count tables without mentioning variable names in a data table within r

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

Is there a way to create a count/frequency table for all variables in a data table in R without explicitly mentioning all the variables in the table?

My data table looks like this:
[image]

I need to create count tables for all variables in the table without mentioning the variable names in the data table.

For e.g. a Smoke frequency table could look like this:
[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Try `lapply(your_data[, -1], table)` (not tested)

Comment: Could you provide the data instead of an image using `dput(data)`

Comment: Thanks Markus! When used with View- it does contain the counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try <- data.frame(id= c(1,2,3,4,5),
                smoke= c(1,0,1,1,0),
                run= c(1,0,0,1,1),
                eat= c(0,1,1,1,1),
                sleep = c(1,0,0,1,1)) #from Girish

X <- lapply(try[,-1], table) #As suggested by markus

View(X)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @markus . Just wanted to add the following -

```
try <- data.frame(id= c(1,2,3,4,5),
                    smoke= c(1,0,1,1,0),
                    run= c(1,0,0,1,1),
                    eat= c(0,1,1,1,1),
                    sleep = c(1,0,0,1,1))
X <- lapply(try[,-1], table) #As suggested by markus


func1 <- function(x){
  y <- as.data.frame(x)
  colnames(y) <- c("Values", "Frequency")
  y
}
func1(X$sleep)
```

Output -

```
> func1(X$sleep)
  Values Frequency
1      0         2
2      1         3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Girish-for detailed code. Code from Markus works well. The only thing would be to View(X).